# My mission is clear... what am I?

Tags: riddle

I tunnel towards myself.

I am pinched into submission.

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me.

I will not go quietly.

I will entangle you still.

If I was a meat eater...

Comment: I have another riddle that got put on hold. I found that when a question is on hold it cannot receive an official correct answer. I am providing the answer to this riddle myself in order to preempt it being put on hold; I really don't like it when the answer isn't allowed to be known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am:

> Earbuds

I tunnel towards myself.

> When they are pushed into the tunnel openings of your ears, they are pushed towards one another. if you kept pushing them in the same direction (through the meat in your head) they would meet in the middle of your head.

I am pinched into submission.

> The earbuds are kept in place by being pinched by the narrowing of your ear-holes.

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me.

> The earbuds are engineered to fit into your ear-holes. your ear-holes become the straightjacket for the earbuds, holding them in place.

I will not go quietly.

> They make sounds, that is what they are for.

I will entangle you still.

> that terrible wire that goes from the earbuds to your smart-phone is always getting snagged and tangled on things.

If I was a meat eater...

> If earbuds become carnivorous and could eat their way further into your head; that would be one of the most terrifying carnivores.

Comment: I did consider and reject earphones several days ago because I didn't consider them to be tunneling when placed in the ear and I didn't consider the two earbuds to be the same "self". I thought nail-cutters, ear piercings etc. all fit the description better than that because they actually tunnel toward themselves and do meet.

Answer (score 4):

<s>Might be a stretch but:</s> I think it is:

> <s>Sausage links</s> Blender

I tunnel towards myself.

> <s>They end usually curve up inwards towards the middle, looking like a slight smile.  In chain form they can also be wrapped around each other in a spiral like fashion.</s> The Blender's blades are angled towards the center, when it comes to life the food/drink is funneled down and to the center.

I am pinched into submission.

> <s>Each section of the chain pinches off a new sausage</s> People press the buttons over and over again to pulse the contents.

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me.

> <s>The meat is pushed through/into the casing and is shaped by it.</s> The different styled blades are interchangeable and designed to fit the base.

I will not go quietly.

> <s>When you eat it, for many people it causes gas or worse</s> When you turn it on it is loud

I will entangle you still.

> <s>Referring just to the links part, links form a chain that can entangle people</s>  It mixes all the contents together

If I was a meat eater...

> <s>Made of meat. Or if you where a meat eater, you'd enjoy eating these.</s> It would slice through meat very easily with its sharp blades

Comment: "I will not go quietly." seems like a nice and elegant warning for your surroundings. I plan to reuse it.

Comment: I like your answer. It is not what I am looking for, but I especially like your interpretation of the straightjacket; that is the general idea; I was afraid that was going to be a red herring that would be too confusing.

Comment: @ErikGecas how about this?

Comment: I like both of those guesses. The object is much more personal than that though. There is a decent chance that you are being its straightjacket right now, and if you are using this object, it is good that it cannot continue to tunnel until it touches itself; it would be bad; it would involve too much meat. (that sounds gross; it really isn't gross)

Comment: @ErikGecas it's starting to sound either really gross or really naughty 

Comment: Wow, I am sorry, I just reread that and that sure does sound bad... the riddle really isn't like that. The answer is a very normal G-rated thing...

Answer (score 3):

How about a...

> vacuum cleaner.

I tunnel towards myself.

> A vacuum cleaner creates a tunnel of sorts in a pile of dirt or dust by pulling the dirt toward itself.

I am pinched into submission.

> By pinching or kinking the hose of a vacuum, it will lose suction.

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me.

> When a vacuum bag fills up, it fits very tightly inside.

I will not go quietly.

> Vacuums are noisy to operate.

I will entangle you still.

> An electrical cord on a vacuum will often tangle around the legs of the operator.

If I was a meat eater...

> Sometimes vacuums are used for sealing food packages or containers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you a...

> Clasp or a buckle

I tunnel towards myself.

> On a belt the start and end are a clasp or buckle

I am pinched into submission.

> some clasps or buckles can be opened by pinching it

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me.

> buckles and clasps are used to tighten and lock a straightjacket into palce

I will not go quietly.

> People sometimes struggle to open a locked buckle/clasp or some buckles and clasps(I am thinking the ones on watch bands) make a sound when released.

I will entangle you still.

> A buckle/clasp is usually used to tighten pieces of clothing into place to keep them from moving.

If I was a meat eater...

> This one I am not sure about

Comment: Nice answer. I especially like that you guessed a very common everyday object. The answer I am looking for is possibly an even more common everyday object.

Comment: I was thinking maybe just the object  'On a ___ ...' from your second spoiler tag.

Answer (score 1):

> Are you a hole punch, biting into a stack of paper like a carnivore, tunneling to the anvil that is your own base plate, with a crunching noise ? 
>  No wait, actually a **[paper staple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staple_(fastener)#Paper_staples)** fits better: it also does all of the above and also "entangles" the paper together, plus the staple is bent and "fitted" to the paper's thickness!

Comment: I like your answer, the answer I am looking for is an object that can make a lot of noise (more noise than a stapler or hole puncher).

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> donut because it's a round tunnel, is pinched when made at the bakery, is put into a box, the people eating it are loud because of the sugar, and it is addictive

i'm not sure about the meat eater though.

Comment: No, the answer isn't donut, but your answer is like a donut commercial; I now feel like I need to go get some donuts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> A shoelace, or bootlace

I tunnel towards myself:

> Shoelaces thread through the eyelets back towards themselves so that they can be tied

I am fitted to this straightjacket, it is not fitted to me

> The straightjacket is the shoe

I will not go quietly

> I am not sure of this, but when the shoelace goes (with the shoe), footsteps are made

I will entangle you still

> People trip over their own shoelaces, especially if they become untied

If I was a meat eater..

> The shoe could be said to swallow the foot, the shoelace prevents the foot from slipping from the shoe, fortunately neither shoes nor shoelaces are carnivorous

Comment: I like your answer; especially the meat eater part. The answer I am looking for, though, really does make sounds, and it is not the straightjacket.

Comment: I wasn't convinced about the 'not going quietly' part of the answer, but I thought everything else fitted wonderfully.